# got the following error while declaring the timestamp sa data type in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

My time stamp value format is like 20200203160857. I am declaring my variable time stamp as TIMESTAMP.

```
time_stamp TIMESTAMP NULL,
```

and I am copying a csv file in that the time stamp value is as shown above. While inserting i got the following error.

> date/time field value out of range: "20200203160857"\n HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.\n

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the complete code of your function as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please. ([edit] your question do not post code in comments)

Answer (score 1):

use `to_timestamp()` function like below to manage your format of timestamp

```
to_timestamp('20200203160857', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
```